# Can a website detect which method you are using to connect (LL2P, SSTP and PPTP)

Tags: networking, network-programming, vpn, packet, pptp

When you connect to a website using a VPN with the same IP however using a different type of connection each time (LL2P, SSTP and PPTP) can the website detect the difference between these connection.

For example lets say you connect using an SSTP connection the first time but the next time you decide to use an LL2P connect. Is the website able to detect that you've used another method to connect to the website?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know No*

The tunneling protocol is only used only between you and your VPN provider. Once your traffic reaches the VPN provider, the tunneling headers are removed and your packets are forwarded to the destination as if sent by the VPN provider.

*The only caveat I can think of is that the different tunneling methods have different header lengths. So if the website is receiving 1492 packets from you, it might suspect that either you or your ISP is using a tunneling protocol with an 8 byte header (since a 1500 MTU is generally the norm). However, if you switch to some other tunneling protocol, one that uses 10 byte headers for instance, then the packet sizes might shrink to 1490.